# Fabric.js - Moving image loaded from url receiving error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

I'm new to fabric.js, and I try to add it to a React application. I created the canvas on window so it would be global and available from all components:

`window.fabricCanvas = new Fabric.fabric.Canvas();`

When clicking an 'Add Image' button the following function is called:

```
addImage() {
Fabric.fabric.Image.fromURL(this.state.imageUrl, function(img) {
  let oImg = img.set({left: 50, top: 100, angle: -15}).scale(0.5);
  window.fabricCanvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
  window.fabricCanvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
})};
```

The image is indeed loaded, but if I try moving\scaling the image it disappears, and I get this error in console:

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at klass._render (fabric.js:18795)
```

which refers to this line in their code:

`if (this.isMoving === false && this.resizeFilters.length && this._needsResize()) {`

Any ideas what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You need to pass a HTML canvas element when you create the fabric canvas like `new Fabric.fabric.Canvas(document.getElementById('mycanvas'))`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it is possible (you can see that working example: https://jsfiddle.net/STHayden/2pncoLb5/) to not pass the canvas and later use: fabricCanvas.initialize(canvasElement, {
      height: 300,
      width: 300,
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem with 2.0.0-beta2, but it's working fine with the stable 1.7.11 so try switching to that.